# Transfer function of an op amp with an Y or delta

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, bode-plot, frequency-response, inverting-amplifier

What's the transfer function of the op-amp with a Delta from figure one? Such circuit can be easily converted into an Y, figure 2. Tina is calculating the transfer function from the Y circuit as
H(s) = -(Zyb(s)/Zya(s)), it simply ignored Zyc. One way I could thinkg of, considering the Y circuit was: H(s) = (-(Zyb(s)/Zya(s))*(Zin/(Zyc(s) + Zin)), where Zin is the input impedance of the inverting op amp, a datasheet value. So, is there a way to calculate such transfer function cosidering the 3 impedances on both configurations, Y and Delta without calling Zin?

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: A TF analysis requires an input and an output. Your figure 1 doesn't show them.

Comment: I'm confused. Is there supposed to be an input at the junction of Zac and Zab in the top diagram?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy no, it's the equivalent of the Y circuit, shown on figure 2, so, same input and same output. I will edit the image.

Comment: @Andyaka Just reffered Vindelta, Vodelta, VinY and VoY. Considering they are equivalent circuits, upon doing a Delta-Y/Y-Delta conversion, VoY/VinY = Vodelta/Vindelta.

Comment: The opamp input impedance is both extremely high and very badly undefined. For any normal values of the other components, it will have an undetectable effect on the input impedance; just ignore it and assume it is infinite.

Comment: @KevinWhite, right, according to the TL082 datasheet, which I intend to use, it's 1Tohms. So, any sugestion other than: H(s) = (-(Zyb(s)/Zya(s))*(Zin/(Zyc(s) + Zin)), which means: H(s) = (-(Zyb(s)/Zya(s))*((10^12)/(Zyc(s) + (10^12))), and we can igonre Zin.

Comment: Zab has no relevance in the circuit you show.

Answer (score 4):

In your top circuit Zab plays no role at all, except to pass some pointless current. It's connected directly across two voltage sources, one (the input) that doesn't care one iota what's connected to it, and the other (the opamp output) which will adopt whatever voltage is necessary to bring its inverting input potential to zero (to equal the voltage at its non-inverting input). Zab represents a redundant load at the opamp output, which may prevent the opamp from opamping, but is otherwise irrelevant because the potential of those two sources are in no way dependent on it.

In the second circuit, it's Zcy which is irrelevant. The opamp draws negligible current at its inputs, meaning that the voltage across Zcy is zero. As far as Tina is concerned, Zcy is connected to nothing at all at one end, and her predicted transfer function is correct.

If you require a transfer function which accounts for opamp imperfections, such as non-zero output impedance, or significant input bias currents, then you will need a much more realistic model than an "ideal opamp". The transfer function will be horrendously complicated, and different for every opamp model out there.

You cannot use "typical" datasheet values to determine input resistance or output resistance, because they change from device to device, and according to the internal conditions of the opamp. Perhaps the output is a better current source than sink. Perhaps input current is not linear with potential. You choose peripheral impedances around an opamp to render these foibles insignificant, so you may ignore them. If they become significant, it's because you're using the wrong values outside the opamp, or the wrong opamp, and you are flirting with failure.

Just understand why Zab and Zcy do not appear in the transfer function. Accept that if they do have some influence, it's because they are exposing the opamp to conditions under which you can no longer apply the usual "ideal" gain (and other) equations.